# What would be alternative ways to model IConvention?

Tags: c#

```
public class Item { /*...*/ }
public class Model { /*...*/ }

public interface IConventionInstanceSelector {
  IConventionInstance Select(Item item);
}

public interface IConventionInstance {
  void ApplyTo(Model model);
}

public interface IConvention {
  bool IsMatchedBy(Item item);
  IConventionInstance CreateInstance(Item item);
}

public class ConventionInstanceSelector : IConventionInstanceSelector {
  readonly List<IConvention<Item>> _conventions;

  public ConventionInstanceSelector(IEnumerable<IConvention<Item>> conventions) {
    _conventions = conventions.ToList();
  }

  public IConventionInstance Select(Item item) {
    foreach(var convention in _conventions) {
      if(convention.IsMatchedBy(item)) {
        return convention.CreateInstance(item);
      }
    }
    return NullConventionInstance.Instance;
  }
}

public class ModelReader {
  IConventionInstanceSelector _selector;

  public ModelReader(IConventionInstanceSelector selector) {
    _selector = selector;
  }

  public Model Read(IEnumerable<Item> items) {
    var model = new Model();
    foreach(var item in items) {
      _selector.Select(item).ApplyTo(model);    
    }
    return model;
  }
}
```

I'm a bit concerned about the specification and factory method  being merged into one interface (IConvention) and that they can be called separately when in fact one depends on the decision of the other. I also get the feeling there's a pattern here I'm not seeing.

Just to give a little bit more context: I'm trying to build an API whereby people can build their own conventions that get applied to an input stream (an enumeration of items in this case) and have each convention apply a transformation on the input (the item in this case) and add it to a model. The main concern is the convention represents both the fact an item satisfies the convention as well as the logic to apply it to the model AND the fact that how I've modeled it right now, those are two distinct operations whereby the latter relies on the first to be able to do it's job properly. It's like specification pattern meets factory pattern.

Comment: Do you have some (unit)test code excuting this? Makes it a lot easier to review if one doesn't have to imagine the usage. You also partially answer your own question - specification and factory are two different responsibilities, and should be separated in their own classes. You could however group them in something called "ConventionSomething" perhaps?

Comment: No, this is the result of some loose modeling. The idea is that people can define their own conventions. For that they need to tell when an item matches their convention and what should happen to the model once it's matched. I'm looking for alternative ways of modeling that.

Comment: There's a rather nice example of the specification pattern over at wikipedia with links to further reading. I'd just go with already established ways to do it. And separate factory from spec ofc.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on delegating to a factory, yet still keep the two methods as a kind of facade. Will post an update once I'm satisfied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the combination of a Specification and another method is not that unusual - it's called the [Tester-Doer Pattern](https://web.archive.org/web/20160219222750/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/03/16/396787.aspx) (although to be fair, I'm not sure whether it's a bona-fide *pattern*, as I've never seen it described outside of .NET). Even so, despite the precedence, I completely understand why you dislike the [Temporal Coupling](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling.aspx/) it implies. So which alternatives are available?

The first refactoring we could apply is to change the definition of IConvention to emply a [Maybe monad](https://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2011/01/monads-in-c-5-maybe.html). Assuming that we've defined a `Maybe<T>` class, IConvention now looks like this:

```
public interface IConvention
{
    Maybe<IConventionInstance> CreateInstance(Item item);
}
```

This would allow you to in a type-safe way to check whether or not an IConventionInstance instance could be created from the item.

However, once you realize that a [Maybe monad really is nothing more than a special case of IEnumerable](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/02/04/TheBCLAlreadyHasAMaybeMonad.aspx/), you could consider refactoring IConvention once more:

```
public interface IConvention
{
    IEnumerable<IConventionInstance> CreateInstances(Item item);
}
```

In the normal implementation, an implementation would return zero or one item.

This would make the ConventionInstanceSelector and IConventionInstanceSelector types redundant (always a good thing), and you could implement the ModelReader class like this (caveat: I haven't tried to compile it):

```
public class ModelReader {
    IEnumerable<IConvention> _conventions;

    public ModelReader(IEnumerable<IConvention> _conventions) {
        _conventions = conventions;
    }

    public Model Read(IEnumerable<Item> items) {
        var model = new Model();

        var conventionInstances = from item in items
                                  from c in _conventions
                                  from ci in c.CreateInstances(item)
                                  select ci;
        foreach(var ci in conventionInstances) {
            ci.ApplyTo(model);
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I right in assuming the Maybe<IConventionInstance> monad is better suited if I want to stop iterating conventions as soon as I find the first one that applies? This could be a different one for each item, of course. The thing is, conventions only judge applicability by the state of the item passed in. They don't know if a previous evaluated convention was applicable or not (as it should be). That's probably why I modelled the IConventionInstanceSelector in the first place, to make this kind of behavior explicit. Penny for your thoughts :-)

Comment: I didn't understand all of that, but what I usually do is to let `Maybe<T>` implement `IEnumerable<T>` - in this way, you get the explicitness of `Maybe<T>` *and* the convenience of LINQ.

Comment: I must be talking Chinese then. Thanks nonetheless, will try it out.